# C string functions

Tags: c, string, find, substring, substr

In C, how do I extract the first n characters from a string until I find a space in the string? Essentially, which C function will find the position of the next space for me and which C function will give me a substring? I am thinking in terms of C++. such as:

```
string str = "Help me Please!";
int blankPos = str.find(' ');
str.substr(0, blankPos);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `strchr` to find the space.
2. Allocate a new `char` buffer to hold the substring.
3. Copy the substring into the buffer with `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

hint: `strchr()`

I need to type some more characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[] = "Help me Please";    // Source string
char newstr[80];                  // Result string

// Copy substring characters until you reach ' ' (i.e. "Help")
for (i=0; str[i] != ' '; i++) {
  newstr[i] = str[i];
}
newstr[i] = 0;                    // Add string terminator at the end of substring
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..

Answer (score 0):

```
char* str = "Help me Please";
int i =0;

//Find first space
while(str[i] != ' '){
  i++;
}
char* newstr;
newstr = strndup(str+0,i);
```

I guess you could also use strchr() to get the first space in the string.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `strndup` is not a standard C function. And by the way, shouldn't it be `!=` in the while condition?

Comment: @ChristianRau: This is why I thought I could use it.http://linux.die.net/man/3/strndup

Comment: Well, it's a POSIX extension but it's not in the C standard. You should at least remark this platform-dependence in the answer if you really want to use this function.

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like:

```
#include <string.h>

const char *str = "Help me Please";

//find space charachter or end of string if no space found
char *substr, *space = strchr(str, ' ');
int len = space ? (space-str) : strlen(str);

//create new string and copy data
substr = malloc(len+1);
memcpy(substr, str, len);
substr[len] = 0;
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `int` for the length, `size_t` is the right type.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the first part of the string, use `strchr()` as everyone has suggested.  If you're looking to break a string into substrings delimited by spaces, then look into `strtok()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant allowing to use more than one character as delimitter.

```
char str[] = "Help me Please";
char newstr[80]; 

char *p = strpbrk(str, " \t\xA0");   /* space, tab or non-breaking space (assuming western encoding, that part would need adaptation to be trule portable) */
if(p)
  strlcpy(newstr, str, p - str + 1);
else
  newstr[0] = 0;
```

`strlcpy` is not standard but widespread enough to be used. If it is not available on the platform, it's easy to implement. Note that `strlcpy` always puts a 0 at the last position copied, therfore the +1 in the length expression.